# How to test Window Application by pywinauto

Tags: python, frameworks, pywinauto

I have code bellow copy from website : https://pywinauto.github.io/ :

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys("pywinauto Works!", with_spaces = True)
```

I have a question are : how to know Notepad have UntitledNotepad control. I use Autoit to get control info but can't get info of some controls, can't get UntitledNotepad control, but why code above know UntitledNotepad in Notepad. Please show me way to know UntitledNotepad control exist in Notepad.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from pywinauto.application import Application
>>> app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
>>> window = app.top_window ()
>>> window.print_control_identifiers ()
Control Identifiers:

Notepad - 'Untitled - Notepad'    (L183, T308, R1798, B937)
['Untitled - NotepadNotepad', 'Untitled - Notepad', 'Notepad']
child_window(title="Untitled - Notepad", class_name="Notepad")
   |
   | Edit - ''    (L191, T359, R1790, B929)
   | ['Untitled - NotepadEdit', 'Edit']
   | child_window(class_name="Edit")
   |
   | StatusBar - ''    (L191, T906, R1790, B929)
   | ['StatusBar   Ln 1, Col 1  ', 'StatusBar', 'Untitled - NotepadStatusBar']
   | child_window(class_name="msctls_statusbar32")
>>> window = app.window (best_match = "UntitledNotepad")
>>> window.exists ()
True
>>> window = app["UntitledNotepad"]
>>> window.exists ()
True
>>> window = app.UntitledNotepad
>>> window.exists ()
True
>>> window = app.window (best_match = "Untitled - Notepad")
>>> window.exists ()
True
>>> window = app["Untitled - Notepad"]
>>> window.exists ()
True
>>> window.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
>>> window.exists ()
True
>>> window = app.window (class_name="Notepad")
>>> window.exists ()
True
>>> window = app.window (title="Untitled - Notepad")
>>> window.exists ()
True
```

https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: I write code bellow : 
    app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
    app.Notepad.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
    window = app.top_window()    
    window.print_control_identifiers()

But it not show Ok control info

Answer (score 0):

I write code bellow :

```
    app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
    app.Notepad.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
    window = app.top_window()    
    window.print_control_identifiers()
```

But it not show Ok button info of About Notepad view.

It only show info bellow :

```
    Starting test: EmptyProject.Test.Test
20191219 16:37:39.197 : INFO : Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'About Notepad'    (L1019, T401, R1610, B930)
['About NotepadDialog', 'Dialog', 'About Notepad']
child_window(title="About Notepad", class_name="#32770")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L1085, T543, R1582, B545)
   | ['Static', 'About NotepadStatic', 'Static0', 'Static1', 'About NotepadStatic0', 'About NotepadStatic1']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L1079, T563, R1116, B603)
   | ['Static2', 'About NotepadStatic2']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - 'Microsoft Windows'    (L1128, T563, R1531, B583)
   | ['Static3', 'Microsoft Windows', 'Microsoft WindowsStatic']
   | child_window(title="Microsoft Windows", class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - 'Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.557)'    (L1128, T583, R1592, B603)
   | ['Static4', 'Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.557)', 'Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.557)Static']
   | child_window(title="Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.557)", class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - '© 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.'    (L1128, T603, R1548, B623)
   | ['© 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.', '© 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.Static', 'Static5', '© 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.Static0', '© 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.Static1']
   | child_window(title="© 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.", class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - ''    (L1128, T623, R1548, B643)
   | ['© 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.Static2', 'Static6']
   | child_window(class_name="Static")
   | 
   | Static - 'The Windows 10 Enterprise operating system and its user interface are protected by trademark and other pending or existing intellectual property rights in the United States and other countries/regions.'    (L1128, T643, R1548, B723)
   | ['Static7', 'The Windows 10 Enterprise operating system and its user interface are protected by trademark and other pending or existing intellectual property rights in the United  <truncated>
Ending test: EmptyProject.Test.Test
```

Comment: <truncated> indicates that you did not print the full output. The OK button is listet if you print everything.

Comment: How to print everything ? please help me

Comment: `app.AboutNotepad.dump_tree()` ? Child dialog is another top level window in case of `Application(backend="win32")`.